# How can magit 2.x "git rebase --interactive master" from my branch dev-feature-1?

Tags: magit

In 1.x magit I often would rebase my local branch to master, the equivalent of:

```
git checkout master
git pull --rebase
git checkout dev-feature-1
git rebase --interactive master
```

In 1.x magit this was super fast and simple:

```
b b master
F F
b b dev-feature-1
E
```

In 2.x magit it seems like this "rebase to another branch" functionality is gone, or very difficult to find? I read through the magit doc section on rebasing and it seems to assume the only place to rebase to is your currently set upstream. I don't want my upstream to change, it should remain origin/dev-feature-1, I just need to rebase -i against master to get my branch up-to-date.

Has this functionality been removed from magit, or is it called something else now? Maybe there are just more steps that make this formerly simple/frequent operation more complex and slow? Or maybe I'm just missing how to do it in my quick read of the docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd>. Now you are asked what branch you want to rebase to. Instead of just pressing <kbd>RET</kbd> without reading the prompt (which would cause the default to be used, i.e. the upstream branch) instead select/type the branch you actually want to rebase to and *then* press <kbd>RET</kbd>.

**Edit**: Starting with `v2.4` the <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> binding has been replaced with three new bindings. <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd> rebases onto the configured push-remote, <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>u</kbd> onto the configured upstream, and <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> onto any other branch.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I wanted. For my interactive use case, it looked like this:
    r -i r
    master